# chrome binary not found

Tags: javascript, node.js, google-chrome, selenium-webdriver

(node:5864) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: WebDriverError: unknown error: cannot find Chrome binary
at Object.throwDecodedError (C:\Users\lenovo\Desktop\dev\lecture01\automation01\node_modules\selenium-webdriver\lib\error.js:550:15)
at parseHttpResponse (C:\Users\lenovo\Desktop\dev\lecture01\automation01\node_modules\selenium-webdriver\lib\http.js:565:13)
at Executor.execute (C:\Users\lenovo\Desktop\dev\lecture01\automation01\node_modules\selenium-webdriver\lib\http.js:491:26)
at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:97:5)
(node:5864) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection. This error originated either by throwing inside of an async function without a catch block, or by rejecting a promise which was not handled with .catch(). To terminate the node process on unhandled promise rejection, use the CLI flag `--unhandled-rejections=strict` (see https://nodejs.org/api/cli.html#cli_unhandled_rejections_mode). (rejection id: 1)
(node:5864) [DEP0018] DeprecationWarning: Unhandled promise rejections are deprecated. In the future, promise rejections that are not handled will terminate the Node.js process with a non-zero exit code.

i tried reinstalling chrome.